# Linq2SQL - selecting items using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, reflection

I'm trying to load a collection of entities using Linq2SQL. The problem is, I dont know what the entities are,`IList<object>`. I have tried to select them using reflection, but I get an out of memory error when I do the select, I presume because the context is unable to parse my expression,and is loading everything from the DB.

If anyone has any advice on this, or an alternative way to do what I want, please let me know.

```
foreach (object entity in requiredEntities)
{
   Type entityType = entity.GetType();
   IQueryable<object> entityTable = (IQueryable<object>)dataContext.GetTable(entityType);               

   // grab the objects primary key field
   var pkeyField = entityType.GetProperties().SingleOrDefault(p =>
                   p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute),true)
                   .Cast<System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute>() 
                   .Any(attrib => attrib.IsPrimaryKey));

   object pkeyValue = pkeyField.GetValue(entity,null);

   Func<object,bool> primaryKeySelector = o => pkeyField.GetValue(o,null) == pkeyValue;

   // crash here, out of memory exception
   object result = entityTable.Where(primaryKeySelector).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: oh, and i'd like to avoid dynamic linq if possible

Comment: is the set of `requiredEntities` of a single type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using a delegate you are forcing it to use LINQ-to-Objects, which is why it is running out of memory. What you need to do is build an `Expression` instead. Equally, it is bad practice to use the attributes as that is not the only model that LINQ-to-SQL supports; it is preferable to look at `dataContext.Mapping.GetMetaType(entityType)` to get the primary key.

If you have 4.0, the following should work:

```
var entityType = typeof(User);
var metaType = dataContext.Mapping.GetMetaType(entityType);
var member = metaType.DataMembers.Single(m => m.IsPrimaryKey).Member;

var param = Expression.Parameter(entityType);
var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, member),
    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Expression.Constant(entity), member));
dynamic table = dataContext.GetTable(entityType);

object result = Cheeky(table, body, param);
```

with

```
static T Cheeky<T>(ITable<T> source, Expression body, ParameterExpression param)
    where T : class
{
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
    return source.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks. Never knew you could pass a dynamic type to a generic method like that.

Comment: @jasper actually, that is one of the few uses I have for `dynamic` ;p I like my code static-typed, but `MakeGenericMethod`/`MakeGenericType` etc are a PITA - `dynamic` to the rescue ;p